# Строку в timestamp

Tags: php

Есть формат строки "01.02.2017", нужно получить `timestamp` для БД вида `2017-02-01`.
`strtotime("01.02.2017"); //2001-07-20 17:00:00` - не то.

Пробовать `DateTime::createFromFormat()`?
Оборачивал в `date()`:
`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('02.01.2017')); //2001-07-20 17:00:00`.

При том, что в [черновике](https://ideone.com/lDfNad) все так, как надо.

Comment: `нужно получить timestamp для БД вида 2017-02-01` Это не `timestamp`. `timestamp` это метка времени `unix`. Прочитайте тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как надо делать. Не знаю даже что в нем объяснить?

```
<?php
    $test = new DateTime('01.02.2017');

    echo date_format($test, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Просто [мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-create.php) надо читат.

Comment: Странно. У меня вид `$time = new DateTime($request->time);
        $request->time = date_format($time, 'Y-m-d');` - и не получаю, что нужно. Видимо, проблема не в преобразовании.

Comment: @Tarasovych выводи `$tyme` оно должно быть объект типа `DateTime` посмотри есть оно или нет. по очереди выводи данные и посмотри откуда ошибка начинается